# Motor Bike MSK 2 Kit Turning Radius Problem in unity

Tags: unity

I am working on a Chopper Style Motorbike Simulation game and using the Motor Bike Starter Kit (MSK) in Unity. I want to change the turning radius of my bike according to my game requirement. But in the kit, they are setting this with speed but I don't know where these values are changing. I have also tweaked the values of the Bike Control Script from the Inspector and in the script too but didn't get the desired results. If someone work on this kit please help me out to get rid of this problem.

[image]

Comment: This sounds like something you should reach out to the creators of that script about. It's unlikely that a user here will purchase a $45 asset just to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @DMGregory I have already contacted them but they didn't respond back